# some help on Em.Route#send?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am trying to implement router events and using the send function of the router to trigger the events on the router. But couldn't get any documentation on this.
What I am trying to implement is that I am raising an event from controller/view to get the data from the server. And the events asynchronously fetches the data from the server and when the data has been successfully fetched I wanted to initialize the child view of the view from where I called the event i.e. I need to know when the data has been fetched. But I don't think the events on router returns anything such that I can know when the call has been over.
Something like:
**View:**

```
Em.View.extend({
   click: function(){
       var recordsPromise = this.get('controller.target').send('getRecords');
       recordsPromise.done(this.initiateProtocol);
   },

   showChild: false,
   initiateProtocol: function(){
       //this showChild is used as a condition in the template to show/hide
       // the childview. And is being set after the call completed 
       // successfully
       //here childOneView is present some other js file and is fetched using requirejs
       require(['childOneView'], $.proxy(function(childOneView){
           this.set('childOne', childOneView.extend({
               templateName: 'childOne'
           });
           this.set('showChild', true); 
       }, this));

   }
}
```

**Router**

```
Em.Route.extend({
    events: {
        getRecords: function(){
            //make an ajax call to fetch the records and return the ajax as a
            // promise
        }
    }
});
```

**Template**

```
{{#if view.showChild}}
    {{view view.childOne}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: are you using ember-data?

Comment: @intuitivepixel No, I am not using ember-data. Just a simple ajax call to a service.

Comment: what framework are you planning to use for the "promise"? the famous discourse.org app that's made with ember but without ember-data uses this one https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js

Comment: @intuitivepixel I was planning to use simple jQuerry for handling promises. As shown in [html5rocks link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/). But using promise was just an example, if there is some other way around to do this, then that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idiomatic Ember approach would be a bit different. Send the action up to the controller and let it bubble to the route, and then set properties that your view will respond to via bindings:

**View**

```
App.RecordsView = Em.View.extend(Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport, {
  click: function(){
    this.triggerAction({action: 'getRecords'})
  }
});
```

**Controller**

```
App.RecordsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  content: [],
  isLoaded: false
});
```

**Template**

```
<!-- records.handlebars -->
{{#if isLoaded}}
  render stuff here... perhaps {{#each this}}{{someRecordProperty}}{{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

**Router**

```
App.RecordsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  events: {
    getRecords: function(){
      var controller = this.controllerFor('records');
      $.ajax(...).then(function(data){
        Em.run(function(){
          controller.setProperties({
            content: data.foo,
            isLoaded: true
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That approach would have sufficed, but my real problem was not to know when to render my view. I was using requirejs and wanted to fetch my child view when the data has been successfully fetched from the server. And set it in the function which will be called on success of the call, i.e. I wanted to get resources when needed. I have updated my question to better show my requirements.

Comment: I have found a way out. We can use callbacks and call the method from the route events to be run after the records fetching. The data will be set to the controller after successful completion of the call which can be accessed in the template. I have a sample fiddle for this approach here: http://jsbin.com/ajuwis/4/edit . But I don't if this is the correct way or is there some better way for this?

Comment: IMO, you will end up with a cleaner architecture if the actions you send from the view to the controller/router are "no strings attached". No callbacks, no promises, no return values. Instead just have your view bind to or observe controller properties/events that you set from the router.